# IIS Logs even unauthenticated users

Tags: logging, windows-authentication, iis-8

I'm planning to get some information by processing IIS Log files (after I imported them into SQL Server database).

Now, even if user gives wrong username/password, but request to a file that exists on the server, it is logged and I cannot detect weather the user has received the file, or not.

I want to process only requests that are responsed without error.

The environment uses Windows authentication mode.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the `sc-status` in the log entry. [This is a list of http status codes from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) but basically any request that result in a status code in the 200s (usually a `200 OK`) it means a successful request.

Requests that weren't authenticated will result in a `401 Unauthorized` or maybe even `403 Forbidden`

Basically you know the outcome of the request based on the status code. IIS also gives you `sc-substatus` and `sc-win32-status` for more debugging that is [available here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891)